# JavaScript Anonymous Function and Input Params

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand how to properly pass parameters to anonymous functions. It seems like my 'this' is not pointing to where I was hoping it would go.  What am I doing wrong?

JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Chiliyago/NvGs8/3/

```
function initUTCDate() {
    var $date = new Date();
    var $dateUTC = new Date($date.getUTCFullYear(), $date.getUTCMonth(), $date.getUTCDate(), $date.getUTCHours(), $date.getUTCMinutes(), $date.getUTCSeconds());
    return $dateUTC;
}

$(function () {

    var setUTCDateTime = function (timeType) {

        var $input = $(this);

        var $d = initUTCDate();

        if (timeType == "GMT") {
            $input.val($d.toGMTString());
        } else {
            $input.val("false");
        }
    };

    $('input[data-ucw-currDateTime]').each(setUTCDateTime("GMT"));


});
```

Comment: _$date_ -- what kind of notation is that?

Comment: @zerkms Yeah but `$date` in this scenario is *not* a jQuery object

Comment: It seems to be producing a date correctly.  Not sure I see a problem with that portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
$(function () {
    var setUTCDateTime = function (timeType) {
        return function () {
            var $input = $(this);

            var $d = initUTCDate();

            if (timeType == "GMT") {
                $input.val($d.toGMTString());
            } else {
                $input.val("false");
            }
        };
    };

    $('input[data-ucw-currDateTime]').each(setUTCDateTime("GMT"));
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NvGs8/4/